# Mac: mkdir: backup-git-apple: Operation not permitted

Tags: git, macos

MacOS version: 10.13.4

- Attempting to install a newest-version `git`
- when `brew install git` succeed, need backup(remove) the old-version git
- when use `sudo mkdir /usr/bin/backup-git-apple` in the path `usr/bin`
- An error occurred: `mkdir: backup-git-apple: Operation not permitted`

I don't know why `sudo` be permitted... (now my git version still old :(  ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up your old copy of `git` to `~/bin/`:

`mkdir ~/bin/backup-git-apple`

`~/bin/` should still be in your `$PATH` environment variable, so if you want to run the old version, you should be able to do so seamlessly.